# A shell script "getopts error"

Tags: bash, shell, unix, getopts

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 <-lu> <string>"
    exit 1
fi
while getopts "lu" OPT
do
    case $OPT in
        u) casechange=0;;
        l) casechange=1;;
        *) echo "usage: -u<upper> || -l<lower> <string>";
            exit 1;;
    esac
done
shift $(( $optind -1 ))
if [ $casechange -eq 0 ]; then
    tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <$string
elif [ $casechange -eq 1 ]; then
    tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' <$string
else
    echo "fatal error"
    exit 1
fi
```

I get two errors:

- `line 15: shift -1: shift count out of range`
- `line 19: $string: ambiguous redirect`

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Where do you define `$string`?

Comment: nowhere, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OPTIND` needs to be in uppercase letters. Bash is case sensitive by default. That makes `$optind` empty and you're effectively trying to shift by -1.

Also, after processing the options, you need to do something with nonoption arguments:
`string="$1"`

and then `tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<<"$string"` for your redirects from a variable.
Lastly, your sad path outputs should be to `stderr` (`>&2`).

All combined (+some minor improvements):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
    echo "usage: $0 <-lu> <string>" >&2
    exit 1
fi
while getopts "lu" OPT
do
    case $OPT in
        u) casechange=0;;
        l) casechange=1;;
        *) echo "usage: -u<upper> || -l<lower> <string>" >&2;
            exit 1;;
    esac
done
shift $(( $OPTIND -1 ))
string="$1"
if [[ "$casechange" -eq 0 ]]; then
    tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' <<<"$string"
elif [[ "$casechange" -eq 1 ]]; then
    tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' <<<"$string"
else
    echo "fatal error" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: with that change, I still get an error on that line.

> line 15: expr 2 -1: syntax error in expression (error token is "2 -1")

Comment: it's listed above your comment

> line 15: expr 2 -1: syntax error in expression (error token is "2 -1")

Comment: @tinfoil_powers: I did not mean the error message. I mean your line of code.

Comment: line 15 is as follows: >shift $((expr $OPTIND -1))

Comment: You don't need no stinking `expr` in there. Double parentheses take care of the math without the need to call an external program. Just like brackets allow you to get by without calling the external `test` program.